# How to sum a column and add it as footer using prettytable

Tags: python, prettytable

I want the sum of the last column ( ie., Column " E ")  and add that as a footer. How to do it? I didn't find any specific function for the same. Though I found a similar post, which wasn't helpful.

```
def printCSVRow(argument1, argument2, argumentSwitch):
 argument1_output = None
 argument2_output = None
 prettyTable.title = 'B1 and B2 values'
 if argument1 is not None:
    argument1_output = argument1.split("\n")[1].split(";")
    if argumentSwitch == 1:
        row = ["B1"]
        row += argument1_output
        prettyTable.add_row(row)
    else:
        row = ["B2"]
        row += argument1_output
        prettyTable.add_row(row)


if argument2 is not None:
    argument2_output = argument2.split("\n")[1].split(";")
    if argumentSwitch == 1:
        row = ["B2"]
        row += argument2_output
        prettyTable.add_row(row)
    else:
        row = ["B1"]
        row += argument2_output
        prettyTable.add_row(row)




def csvHeader(B1):
 headerNames = ["type"]
 headerNames += B1.split("\n")[0].split(";")
 prettyTable.field_names = headerNames

if __name__ == '__main__':
 Handler = main()
 B1 = Handler.run()
 B2 = None
 B3 = None
 csvHeader(B1)
 iteration = 0

while True:

    B3 = Handler.run(B1)
    if B3 == B2:
        printCSVRow(B1,B2, 1)
        print(prettyTable)
    else:
        B2 = B1
        B1 = B3
```

output:

```
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                          B1 and B2 values                                         |
+------+--------+--------+------+-------+--------+------+-----------------+-----------------+-------+
| type |  id1   | start1 | end1 |  id2  | start2 | end2 |     subseqDP    |     hybridDP    |   E   |
+------+--------+--------+------+-------+--------+------+-----------------+-----------------+-------+
|  B1  | target |   87   |  93  | query |   24   |  30  | CAAGGGU&ACCCUUG | (((((((&))))))) | -3.62 |
|  B2  | target |   39   |  45  | query |   98   | 104  | UCCUGGA&UCCAGGA | (((((((&))))))) | -4.37 |
+------+--------+--------+------+-------+--------+------+-----------------+-----------------+-------+
```

The expected output :

```
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                          B1 and B2 values                                         |
+------+--------+--------+------+-------+--------+------+-----------------+-----------------+-------+
| type |  id1   | start1 | end1 |  id2  | start2 | end2 |     subseqDP    |     hybridDP    |   E   |
+------+--------+--------+------+-------+--------+------+-----------------+-----------------+-------+
|  B1  | target |   87   |  93  | query |   24   |  30  | CAAGGGU&ACCCUUG | (((((((&))))))) | -3.62 |
|  B2  | target |   39   |  45  | query |   98   | 104  | UCCUGGA&UCCAGGA | (((((((&))))))) | -4.37 |
+------+--------+--------+------+-------+--------+------+-----------------+-----------------+-------+
|                                         Total                                             |  -7.99|                                     
+------+--------+--------+------+-------+--------+------+-----------------+-----------------+-------+
```

Comment: If you post the code that generated the table it'd be more likely that you'll receive an answer.

Comment: hi @gboffi , I added my code here now

Comment: your using `prettyTable`,have you tried `prettyTable.add_row(['Total,Sum])` at the last

Comment: shubham, I need help with that sum function. How to sum the last column here in pretty table

Comment: @ShubhamShaswat I have used what you've suggested in your comment in my answer below. I've gladly recognized your contribution in my answer, thank you.

Comment: I wonder if my answer had been useful because I'd like to remove it if not.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you are doing the value that you want to sum is the last item in the list `row`, that you can access as `row[-1]` (the negative index means the last element) but beware that this value is a string, if you want to use arithmetic on it you have to convert the string to a floating point number.

Here it is your function (a little streamlined) with the code to compute the `total` at the end of the `if` blocks and the code to output the last line (as suggested by [Shubham Shaswat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7395492/shubham-shaswat) in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60152589/how-to-sum-a-column-and-add-it-as-footer-using-prettytable?noredirect=1#comment106392365_60152589)) at the very end of the function.

```
def printCSVRow(argument1, argument2, argumentSwitch):

    prettyTable.title = 'B1 and B2 values'
    total = 0

    if argument1 is not None:
        row = ["B2"] + argument1.split("\n")[1].split(";")
        if argumentSwitch == 1: row[0] = "B1"
        prettyTable.add_row(row)
        total += float(row[-1])

    if argument2 is not None:
        row = ["B1"] + argument2.split("\n")[1].split(";")
        if argumentSwitch == 1: row[0] = "B2"
        prettyTable.add_row(row)
        total += float(row[-1])

    prettyTable.add_row(["Total", "%.2f"%total])
```